Click with sign & confirm metamask with selenium
first I click to "send" and it will open a new window like this:

I want to click "sign" and after that will have a new window to click confirm:

here is my selenium code:
window_handles = driver.window_handles
metamask_window_handle = window_handles[2]
driver.switch_to.window(metamask_window_handle)
confirm_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/footer/button[2]')))
confirm_button.click() #sign click

The code doesn't work, what's wrong with my code. Please give me some advice. Thank you so much!
p/s: I have try to switch to new metamask window after click send. but not sure it works or the prolem is from wrong elemeter click.

Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.
